# What is the theoretical maximum RPM of a typical aircraft piston engine?

Tags: engine, piston-engine

Given a standard 6-cylinder, direct-drive, horizontally-opposed engine like the Continental IO-550 or Lycoming IO-540, the maximum RPM for those engines is 2700 RPM. That's due to keeping the propeller tip speed under the supersonic range.

But what is preventing these engines from turning at a higher RPM for another, non-aircraft use?

I'm thinking if they would work up to around 5000 RPM or so. Maybe the fuel mapping must be modified? Will the valve-train start to float at that RPM? The application would be automotive, so the load would be far, far less from a duty cycle standpoint than an aircraft application: basically, 5000 RPM would only be seen for a second or two at a time under full (or nearly full) load.

Is there anything else I'm missing? I realize this is a weird question, just doing some thought experimenting.

Comment: Engines are typically geared to max the prop at 2700 RPM for the reason you describe - and instruments typically show prop RPM, not engine RPM. It doesn't mean the engine is running at that speed at all.

Comment: @falstro: Typically?  In my experience, most aircraft engines are direct drive.  Gearing is the exception.

Comment: @jamesqf I typically fly exceptional aircraft. ;) Jokes aside, I'm sure you're correct. I did my training in the DA20 with Rotax, which does have a gearbox. My flight school was also primarily focused on Rotax powered LSAs like the Ikarus C42, my guess is that most of them have gearboxes which would explain why it was mentioned during ground school. The instruments still show prop RPM though, not engine RPM.

Comment: Size related issues.  A Cox 0.049 cubic inch aircraft engine will spin 20,000+ RPM, smaller engines potentially even faster.

Comment: GTSIO-520s, if I recall correctly, turn at 3,300rpm.  The reduction drive takes the prop to 2700ish.  So...at least 3300rpm.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are three factors which limit the possible speed of piston engines:

1. [Flame speed in the fuel-air mixture](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/33746/why-increase-the-number-of-cylinders-in-an-engine-instead-of-increasing-their-vo/33777#33777),
2. relative speed of moving parts, here the pistons in their cylinders, and
3. Valve inertia and [valve float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valve_float).

If the engine runs too fast, the flame front originating from the spark plug will not have traveled far enough to have burnt most of the fuel by the time the piston moves down again. This puts a fundamental limit to the growth in power output over speed in piston engines.

Also, if the relative speed between moving parts is too high, the lubrication will fail and the parts will overheat quickly. In order to run at the highest possible speed, [rotary engines](http://www.century-of-flight.net/new%20site/frames/rotary%20engines_frame.htm) used castor oil, which in turn motivated early aviators to wear long scarves over their mouth so their digestive system would not be compromised by sitting right in the exhaust stream of their engine. Today, lubricants have improved but still set a clear limit to the maximum speed at which a piston engine can be run. Cooling can be managed by pressurizing the cooling system and improving radiator and pump performance while inertial loads on the engine components can be dealt with by lightweight, high-strength materials.

Reducing the [bore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bore_(engine)) will allow a higher speed before the ignition limit bites while reducing the [stroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroke_(engine)) will reduce piston speeds, again allowing a higher engine speed before lubrication fails. An optimimized engine will balance both so that the possible speed can be fully exploited. For the IO-360 and IO-540, those dimensions are 5⅛" and 4⅜", respectively. This places them below the [last generation of big aviation pistons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_R-4360_Wasp_Major) and closer to the typical [interwar engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_Kestrel).

With higher speeds, the valves need to move faster, too. If the force of the valve springs are not sufficient to close the valves quickly enough, compression will suffer, limiting RPM and power. In order to reduce the inertia of each individual valve, the [number of valves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-valve) can be doubled or even tripled.

I could not find reliable data on the engine speed of [Reno Air Race winners](http://www.rarebear.com/bearfacts/), which should come close to the maximum sensible engine speed at that size class. The best I could find was the 3,700 RPM of the [Jumo 213 E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junkers_Jumo_213#Specifications_.28Jumo_213E.29), an engine with 5.9" bore and 6.5" stroke, so I would guess by using good fuel and lubrication, the Lycoming might end up somewhere between 4000 and 4500 RPM. I'm sceptical that much useful power can be extracted at 5000 RPM and am sure that the lifetime at this speed will be measured in minutes, not hours.

Comment: I'm rather skeptical about the lubrication part.  After all, smaller piston engines like motorcycle engines can redline at well over 10K RPM.

Comment: @jamesqf aviation oil is pretty different, and these engines may not be able to effectively use automotive lubricants.  Stroke length affects piston velocity at rpm.  Shorter stroke means lower piston velocity at 10k rpm.

Comment: @BaileyS I'd assume that aero engines use different oil because they're lower-revving, rather than because there's something about aviation that means you couldn't use an oil that would work at 10k rpm.

Comment: @Bailey S: I think you have cause and effect reversed here.  Aviation oils have the characteristics they do because that's what conventional aviation engines need.  If you built an experimental using a high-revving motorcycle engine, you'd use the kind of oil the  manufacturer specifies, not aviation oil.  IOW, it's not anything fundamental to the oil that limits IC engine RPMs to 2700 or so.

Comment: @jamesqf: Do the numbers yourself. Engine speed and stroke are inversely related precisely because piston speed is limited by lubrication.

Comment: @Peter Kämpf: Maybe so, but that lubrication limit is far above the speed of typical aircraft engines, as demonstrated by the fact that there are many engines  (of similar displacement, too, so it's not just a size effect) that do run at much higher speeds.

Comment: @jamesqf: I agree, this is true today but was a limiting factor historically.

Comment: @Peter Kämpf The other posters are right. Right off the top my head I can think of the Yamaha Genesis engine line for the R6 and R1 sport bikes.  The 599cc engine in the R6 had a redline of 16,000 RPM!

Comment: @CarloFelicione The stroke of the Genesis is 44.5 mm (and the redline is [15,800 RPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamaha_YZF-R6#2006_tachometer_problem)). Compare that to the 165 mm of the Jumo 213 and RPMs should have a factor of four between them. Looks about right, given the better performance of modern oils. Also, using three intake valves with their lower inertias helps, too.

Comment: I had a 2.0L car engine (Honda F20C) that redlined at 8100 RPM, so high speeds are certainly possible with standard automotive oil. I don’t know if you could extrapolate the other issues from there to a 9.0L IO-550, though.

Comment: Valve float can be solved with pneumatics or hydraulics - look at the V12 & V10 Formula 1 engines from the 2000s and early 2010s. They ran to 22-24000 RPM. Even current F1 engines (with much lower red lines a mere 14-16000 RPM) still use hydraulically operated valves.

Comment: @FreeMan What was the life time of those F1 engines? Would you trust your life to one in your plane? You are comparing apples to oranges (or maybe pumpkins, who knows)

Comment: Um... Well, this season they're expected to last about 7 races @ ~300km per race (plus practice and qualifying sessions). Yes, I'd trust one, but only for a short trip. ;) My point, though is that while the issues you specify are real, they can be overcome if one throws enough time, money & engineering at it. Probably not with an existing aviation engine, though.

Answer (score 10):

The size and weight of the pistons is going to be a major hurdle. With a 5.25 in bore and a 4.25 inch stroke, the pistons are *massive* and don't change directions very easily—there's only so many Gs you can put a shape this large through at the top and bottom of each stroke before the metal starts deforming. Bounce an open umbrella up and down really fast, and you'll start to get the picture.

Cooling would also be a major factor for non-aviation use. Aircraft engines (more or less rightly) assume that there's going to be a large fan out front and/or 100+ mph of airflow. Liquid cooling would allow the heads to maintain a more constant temperature, but would also add weight and complexity.

If you want a faster-revving flat six that will put out more than 100hp and is suitable for automotive use, I might suggest pulling an engine out of a Honda Goldwing or Valkyrie. Given the edited description, though, I'm guessing you're thinking of a drag racer.

Comment: those super big block V8's based on the chevy 454 ( I think it was as 630 something cubic inch ) had a bore of like 5.0 and stroke of 5.8 and they turned up to 7200RPM.  Obviously race built and highly specialized parts, but its been done :)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the other posts with the general limiting factors being failure at high rpm and cooling being a problem. Assuming reliability isn't a concern for you... what else will be the limiting factor?

Reliability and cooling aside no-one seems to have mentioned intake restriction or valve train.

The first limiting factor will be how much fuel can your engine injest and burn. So is the engine normally aspirated or forced? NA engines are limited by how much fuel and air they can draw in. So: carbs, intake manifold, cam and valves need to be able to flow enough to produce the power you want.  Forced induction makes this a bit simpler.

But as revs rise to produce big HP numbers you are going to hit the glass ceiling of how fast your valve train can function. At some point the valve springs will not be able to close in time (known as valve bounce) and can simply stay open. This affects the  compression and combustion strokes and may result in the piston hitting the valve shortly followed by very unpleasant noises.

My answer was given with a stock aero engine as the starting point, thinking about what limitations you would hit as revs rise. Each limitation can be overcome but the solutions get more complex and expensive as revs rise and you chase bigger HP figures.

Comment: yeah, valve float was one of my first concerns.  and I was thinking turbocharging.

Comment: Yep i agree. But considering OPs question, I tried to answer with a stock aero engine as the starting point.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing physically limiting it but the engines are designed to run optimally in the given range so they may simply not run very well. Of course you could always change the cam timing, spark timing etc. For the record your run of the mill aircraft engine is not all that different than the early Porsche/VW air cooled flat car motors ([which were even used on aircraft at one point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porsche_PFM_3200)). You would need to [cool it at least partial with an oil system](http://www.elephantracing.com/oilhandling/diagram/911-oil-cooler-kit.htm) and partially with [an air fan](http://www.ferdinandmagazine.com/porsche-flat-fan-kit) much as Porsche did on their pre 996 era cars if you did not want to leverage water cooling (and you dont need to). For the record large bore air cooled engines [can develop a lot of horse power and rev very high if built correctly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porsche_917).

For what its worth aircraft engines are far more expensive than their non FAA certified automotive counterparts and you are better off using a car engine simply from a cost perspective.

Comment: yes, plans were to mimic the 911 style cooling with shrouds and fans, and lots of oil capacity and cooling.

Comment: The Porsche Mooney you mention had an engine based on the 911, not the 356/VW.  2 extra cylinders, a LOT more horse power, and in later years, higher RPM limits.  RPM orange line on my '65 356C is at 5k rpms (and the car is cruise-able at near that), redline is at 5500 and you are booking an engine rebuild at 6k.  On the late 70s/early 80s 911sc redline was closer to 7k IIRC...

Comment: @ivanivan both the 911 3.2 motor and the earlier 356 era 4 cylinder were actually certified for flight. The 4 cyl was used iirc on blimps and yes the Mooney had the 911 motor with an added stepper gearbox for the prop.  The redline on my [78 911SC](http://forums.pelicanparts.com/dto_garage.php?do=viewvehicle&vehicle_id=14373) is 6200 RPM but in 5th I am around 3.5K on the highways. 911 Engines with their over cautious bearing setup can be built to redline even higher than that.

Comment: @Dave yup.  The 3.0sc and 3.2 "Carrera" (real Carreras have 4 cams!) engines are darn near bullet proof.

Comment: @ivanivan [that they are...](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xh59e0)

Answer (score 0):

There are mechanical limits to rpm and volumetric efficiency limits to engine RPM.
Mechanical: Piston speed- damaged piston, rod
            Piston acceleration - ring flutter failure
            Valve float- catastrophic valve failure
            Increase RPM results in higher oil temps
Volumetric: Ability to intake air is limited by:
                  Airflow limits of intake system:
                      carb
                      airbox
                      Intake tubes
                      Intake manifolds, and ports, valves, cam design and 
                      timing.
All thees things determine the amount of air the motor is able to intake and that determines the rpm the motor will work best at. More details can be found by looking in a superflow flowbench manual available for free on the net.

Exceed mechanical limits and experience catastrophic failure. I the world of racing I often found mechanical limits by  exceeding them.
Exceed volumetric limits and see loss of torque.

Answer (score 0):

One could come up with a higher revving aircraft engine and gear it down for subsonic prop operation. That is what Porsche did with its [PFM 3200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porsche_PFM_3200) aircraft engine: took it's 911 flat six and geared it down. While it was a very good engine, with about twice the HP of similar displacement aircraft flat sixes, and was used to equip the Mooney M20L, it was also expensive to buy and had a fairly short TBO. Supposedly, the PFM 3200 sounded magnificent on takeoff.

Porsche exited the market in 2007 after $75 million in development costs to produce and sell around 80 engines. Supposedly, they bought back all of the PFM 3200 engines in use for liability reasons.

In contrast, the Continental and Lycoming flat sixes are much simpler, slower turning pushrod engines, built with an emphasis on reliability, not power to weight. Low RPM means no gearbox to gear down for prop operation, and no gearbox to maintain or fail. They are intended to operate at high power output for long periods of time without failing, as opposed to automotive engines that tend to loaf along at low power output, with an occasional burst of full power. Loss of power in an aircraft is a bit more serious than loss of power in a car, hence the emphasis on reliability.

So, if you want a flat six with lots of HP for non aircraft use... don't look at aircraft engines, unless you want an engine that turns slow, that you can floor for an hour or two regularly.

Comment: Porsche also had the "industrial engines" based on the 356 engine, for generators, pumps, watercraft, and even aircraft in the 50s - see http://derwhites356literature.com/New356Stuff/PorscheIndustrialMotors50s60s.html

Answer (score 0):

Niels responds to an old question.

Pushrod valvetrains in big engines (~500 cubic inch class) limit out at about 5000 RPM. Going faster than that usually requires an overhead cam and might yield ~6000 RPM, but past that the reciprocating mass tends to make the engine explode unexpectedly, so to go still faster (and make more power) you reduce the piston size and the crankshaft stroke and add more pistons to maintain displacement.

So instead of a 6-cylinder engine you now have a 10-cylinder engine, and you might make that monster spin faster with dual overhead cams instead of singles. But now you run out of lubrication capacity in the main bearings, so you re-engineer the engine for roller bearing mains.

Now you have to re-engineer the heads for higher heat-rejecting capacity so you do not overheat the exhaust valve seats, which means water-cooling and perhaps also forced-oil cooling.

Now the engine requires supercharging to overcome its pumping losses, so you bolt on a blower to make it spin faster and make more power... but all of this produces a big problem, as follows:

Every crank revolution wears the piston rings, bores, valve train components and crank bearings a tiny little bit. The useful lifetime of the engine is set by how many crank turns you can accumulate before the wear limits are hit. And this means that if you gear the engine down to spin the prop half as fast, you'll accumulate crank turns twice as fast per hour of flight time and you cut the TBO in half- and now you have to overhaul the gearbox and the supercharger as well as the internal engine components in 1000 hours instead of 2000 hours.

Drag-racing engines can push to 7500 RPM or sometimes 10,000 RPM and produce a thousand horsepower or more out of 500 cubic inches, with a TBO of several minutes (no kidding!)- and crowd-pleasing (i.e., truly spectacular) failure modes if any little thing happens to go wrong. So...

High reliability and long life dictate minimizing RPM's and engine complexity, so in internal combustion aircraft engines you stick with big pistons, direct drive, natural aspiration and you live with half a horsepower per cubic inch of displacement at sea level.

Comment: Really interesting! Not at all an answer to the question, but an enjoyable read nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

> But what is preventing these engines from turning a higher RPM, for a non-aircraft use?

Overheating.

It is important to remember that aircraft engines **must** be reliable enough to *maintain enough airspeed for flight*.  It is also important to understand that *thrust* is proportional to the **square of RPM**, so the operating RPM range is not going to be nearly as wide as a motorcycle or a car.

> it is the *drag* of the prop that limits RPM.

For example, an aircraft may maintain level flight at 1500 rpm, but doubles its engine output torque requirement at 2300 rpm to climb.

A more practical solution to boost power output is the *turbocharger*, allowing far more horsepower at a lower RPM, while the "Genesis" motorcycle is screaming 12,000 RPM to make 120 horsepower.

Using an aircraft engine for a high RPM application is a bit like bringing a Clydesdale to the track and racing it against a Thoroughbred.  Generally not a good idea.